# Ng-bind-html y data-toggle="modal" no funcionan

Tags: html, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap, modal

Mi proyecto consiste en crear elementos dom desde js, para esto utilizo angular y su función ng-bind-html, el ng-bind-html me sirve en todo los casos excepto en este.

Quiero que al agregar un texto me añada la siguiente etiqueta.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#modalAcquisitionMode">VER FIGURA MODALIDAD DE ADQUISICIÓN</a>
```

El problema viene que al añadir la etiqueta se eliminan la propiedad data-toggle="modal"y sin ella no me sirve la etiqueta.

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto?

PD:

Al mostrarse en pantalla aparece la etiqueta asi

```
 <a href="#modalAcquisitionMode">VER FIGURA MODALIDAD DE ADQUISICIÓN</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema viene en los atributos que tiene ng-bind-html aprobados para ahref en su libreria, lo que hay que hacer es sencillo.

se debe buscar la variable donde definen los atributos de la etiqueta  en angular-sanitize (en mi caso la variable se llama **uriAttrs**)

```
var uriAttrs = toMap('background,cite,href,longdesc,src,xlink:href,data-toggle');
```

Allí se añade las nuevas propiedades que la librería van a reconocer, en este caso **data-toggle**, pero puedes añadir cualquier atributo nuevo.